# How to Translate english words to pig latin Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm in a beginning computer science class and I'd really like help on my current assignment. The assignment is to make a program that translates english words into pig latin. It gets input from the user and then spits out the translated string. For example, if you input "hello world", the output should be "ellohay orldway". If the first letter of the word is a vowel, however, it just adds "ay" to the end and does not bring the first letter to the back.
The requirement of the assignment is that I have to use two functions in my code. Here is the code I have so far. Sorry it is not very complete.

Would anyone be kind enough to let me know what the next step is?

```
var wordInput = prompt("Please enter a word to be translated into pig latin.").toLowerCase();

var myArray = wordInput.split(" ");

var vowel = function(word){
    switch (word.charAt(0)) {
  case 'a':
    return true;
    break;
  case 'e':
    return true;
    break;
  case 'i':
    return true;
    break;
  case 'o':
    return true;
    break;
  case 'u':
    return true;
    break;
  default:
    return false;
    break;

alert(wordInput + "ay")
}
}

var convertWord = function(word){
    return wordInput.substring(1) + wordInput.substring(0,1);
}


convertWord();

var res = wordInput.charAt(0)
```

Comment: Since you are starting why not try angularjs1.x and ngtranslate they are quite simplified translation and localization functions with them. Worth having a look

Answer (score 0):

interesting question. 
Perhaps in the second function, you can check to see if you have vowel:

```
vowel(word);
if true --> add 'ay'
if false --> swap first letter to end, then at 'ay'
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution algorithm:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {

  var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
  var slicedArr = [];
  var newStr = '';

  if (vowels.indexOf(str[0]) >= 0) { // First letter is a vowel, translate immediately
    return str + 'way';
  }

  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if (vowels.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0) { // Vowel
      return newStr + slicedArr.join("") + 'ay';
    } else { // Consonant
      // Keep slicing from string until you hit a vowel
      slicedArr.push(str[i]);
      newStr = str.slice(i+1);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42003680/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)